# Trying to make this work for multiple cells

Tags: excel

I have made this program that creates groups of 4 cells on sheets 2 and 3 depending on the value of a cell in sheet 1.

```
Sub Two_of_Two()

Dim Two_by_Two(1 To 6) As Range

Dim Diag1 As Range

Dim Diag2 As Range

Dim Horiz1 As Range

Dim Horiz2 As Range

Dim Vert1 As Range

Dim Vert2 As Range

Dim Share1 As Range

Dim Share2 As Range

Dim TopLeft As Range

Dim BottomRight As Range

Dim Black As Integer

Dim White As Integer

 Black = 255

 White = 0

Set Diag1 = Sheet1.Range("E17:F18")

Set Diag2 = Sheet1.Range("H17:I18")

Set Horiz1 = Sheet1.Range("E21:F22")

Set Horiz2 = Sheet1.Range("H21:I22")

Set Vert1 = Sheet1.Range("E24:F25")

Set Vert2 = Sheet1.Range("H24:I25")

Set Two_by_Two(1) = Diag1

Set Two_by_Two(2) = Diag2

Set Two_by_Two(3) = Horiz1

Set Two_by_Two(4) = Horiz2

Set Two_by_Two(5) = Vert1

Set Two_by_Two(6) = Vert2

Dim Cell As Range

Dim Subpixel As Range

For Each Cell In Sheet1.Range("A1")

    Set Share1 = Sheet2.Range("A1:B2")

    Set Share2 = Sheet3.Range("A1:B2")

    Share1.Value = Two_by_Two(Int((6 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)).Value

    If Cell.Value >= 127.5 Then

    Share2.Value = Share1.Value

    ElseIf 127.5 > Cell.Value Then

        For Each Subpixel In Share1

            If Subpixel.Value = Black Then

            Sheet3.Cells(Subpixel.Row, Subpixel.Column) = White

            ElseIf Subpixel.Value = White Then

            Sheet3.Cells(Subpixel.Row, Subpixel.Column) = Black

            End If

        Next Subpixel

    End If

Next Cell

End Sub
```

I want to make it so that this works for multiple cells. Say once the for loop goes on to the next cell A2, it inputs values into the next 2x2 group of cells along. So if A1 in Sheet 1 corresponds to the range ("A1:B2") in Sheets 2 and 3, then B1 in Sheet 1 would be ("C1:D2") in Sheets 2 and 3.

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Please select an answer to help users with the same issue find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up the code quite a bit and looped the Two_by_Two array.

```
Sub Two_of_Two()
    Dim Two_by_Two(1 To 6) As Range
    Dim Diag1 As Range: Set Diag1 = Sheet1.Range("E17:F18")
    Dim Diag2 As Range: Set Diag2 = Sheet1.Range("H17:I18")
    Dim Horiz1 As Range: Set Horiz1 = Sheet1.Range("E21:F22")
    Dim Horiz2 As Range: Set Horiz2 = Sheet1.Range("H21:I22")
    Dim Vert1 As Range: Set Vert1 = Sheet1.Range("E24:F25")
    Dim Vert2 As Range: Set Vert2 = Sheet1.Range("H24:I25")
    Dim Share1 As Range: Set Share1 = Sheet2.Range("A1:B2")
    Dim Share2 As Range: Set Share2 = Sheet3.Range("A1:B2")
    Dim TopLeft, BottomRight, Cell, Subpixel As Range
    Dim Black, White, rndval As Integer
    Dim i As Long

    Black = 255
    White = 0

    Set Two_by_Two(1) = Diag1
    Set Two_by_Two(2) = Diag2
    Set Two_by_Two(3) = Horiz1
    Set Two_by_Two(4) = Horiz2
    Set Two_by_Two(5) = Vert1
    Set Two_by_Two(6) = Vert2

    rndval = Int(6 * Rnd + 1)
    Share1.Value = Two_by_Two(rndval).Value

    If Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) >= 127.5 Then
        Share2.Value = Share1.Value
    Else
        Share2.Value = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)
    End If

    For Each Subpixel In Share1
        If Subpixel.Value = Black Then
            Sheet3.Cells(Subpixel.Row, Subpixel.Column) = White
        ElseIf Subpixel.Value = White Then
            Sheet3.Cells(Subpixel.Row, Subpixel.Column) = Black
        End If
    Next Subpixel
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't help with the problem I'm trying to solve. I need the shares to randomly select one of the ranges from the Two_by_Two array and then when it moves on to the next cell in the original sheet it moves on to the next group of 4 cells on Sheets 2 and 3 to insert the shares.

Comment: Let's see what I can do

Comment: Updated it to randomize the call to `Two_by_Two`